# Diminishing mariginal utility and risk preferences

Tags: microeconomics, utility, expected-utility, risk-aversion

Diminishing marginal utility is a concept only in [cardinal utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_utility) theory rather than [ordinal utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_utility) theory. As diminishing marginal utility implies a concave shape of the utility function, does it necessarily mean that agents with diminishing marginal utility must be risk-averse (also has a function with a concave shape)?

Does cardinal utility theory assume the law of diminishing marginal utility in all of this theory? Could you have increasing marginal utility within cardinal utility theory?

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand the second part of your question. Are you asking if can have utility function with increasing marginal utility? I don't see why you couldn't theoretically have an agent with $e^{\beta \cdot W},\; \beta>0$ preferences. And quadratic utility preferences (which are common and standard in many applications) generally imply a region where marginal utility is increasing (though it may be at negative wealth levels.

Comment: Thanks, so it is possible to have the increasing marginal utility in cardinal theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mas-Colell, Whinston, and Green Proposition 6.C.1 (p. 187) says that for an expected utility maximizer with a Bernoulli utility function $u(\cdot)$ on amounts of money, saying that "the decision maker is risk averse" is equivalent to "$u(\cdot)$ is concave".

However, these other assumptions matter. A concave utility function isn't enough. Diminishing marginal utility in amounts of money doesn't have to imply risk aversion. For example, with gamble $(F)$ taking two values $W_L,\: P(W_L) = \theta$  and $W_H>W_L,\:P(W_H) = 1 - \theta$, and a utility function $u{}$ with diminishing marginal utility in wealth, consider this person's welfare function over risky lotteries $(V)$:
$$V(F, u(), \theta) = u(W_H)$$
This person is not risk averse. They love risk (for example, they prefer a risky lottery to the expected value of that lottery). But, in situations without risk, they have diminishing marginal utility of wealth.

Comment: "these other assumptions" There are no assumptions in your answer that "these" could refer to.

Comment: The other assumptions are that the agent is 1) an expected utility maximizer and 2) has a Bernoulli utility function.

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry.